# AppSync how to check if a variable is an array in javascript resolver

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync-resolver

I'm new in AWS AppSync. I just need to check if a variable is an array. I've already tried following ways but they are not working.

**1. Array.isArray(variable)**

I got an error when I run this code

This seems not to be supported according to this official document while other common Array's functions are clearly stated.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/built-in-objects-functions.html

**2. Using util.isList (@aws-appsync/utils)**

This also doesn't work with this error

```
*'isList' does not exist on type 'Util'.*
```

This function looks like supported only in VTL version

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/utility-helpers-in-util.html

Do anyone have any idea to check if variable is an array?

Answer (score 0):

Went for this hacky solution, probably does not cover all use cases but worked for our scenarios:

```
function isArray(input) {
  return typeof input === "object" && input !== null && typeof input.length === "number";
}
```